# What is a Minion? are they someone who practices sycophancy?

Tags: meaning

The Minions, asked by my children what is a Minion Dad? And being jeered for my answer of "little one eyed yellow people" I slunk to my P.C.

The Cambridge English Dictionary defines **minion**; noun [ C ]; usually disapproving; a person who is not important and who has to do what another person of higher rank orders them to do: With Merriam-Webster following along similar lines.

Whilst a minion is associated with a sycophantic follower by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minion) and also cross referenced by Wikipedia.

The definitions seem to be rather diverse. Why?

Comment: A minion is traditionally a servant or junior employee, usually meaning 'underling, gofer, janitor-level' etc.. However, recently the word has been used in a movie for small yellow cartoon creatures. Wiktionary and Wikipedia are crowd sourced and not authoritative.

Comment: @Brad: To be fair, Wiktionary's *first* definition is similar to the Cambridge one.

Comment: I don't see any issue.  Wiktionary has "a loyal follower, of a more powerful being", Cambridge adds "not important" and slightly modifies "loyal" to /has to follow orders./  but "underling" is the basic idea.  "Sycophatic underling" is put in a second sence in wiktionary.

Comment: @ Michael Harvey Thank you for high lighting the difference between sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wiktionary points out, the word is derived from the French *mignon*, meaning 'darling, favourite'. According to my old *Petit Larousse*, King Henri III of France had a number of (male) favourites known as  *mignons*, with whom he may or may not have had sexual relationships. Over the centuries, the word has lost much of its sense of a *favoured* underling and is usually used for any minor employee.

Comment: Thank you That no doubt also ties up with the sycophantic follower definition. As we could presume that without Henry's patronage they would have nothing (or very little). Which helps understand the divergence.